# Update issue in Jira using Python

Tags: python, jira

I need to update a Jira property using Python. I have tried to use the example provided by Atlassian with no success.

Following the code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

URL = 'https://myurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/TEST-55/properties/customfield_15035?notifyUsers=false'

payload= json.dumps({
    "fields": {
        "customfield_15035": [{"prop1": "xxxx", "prop2": "yyyy", "prop3": "zzzz"}]
    } 
})

headers = {
    "Accept":"application/json"
}

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, passw)

response = requests.request("PUT", URL, headers=headers, auth=auth, data=payload)
print(response.status_code)
```

I am getting response 201, but no property change.

How do I correct the call to update the property using Jira REST webservice?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using the following code:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/{issue_key}"

issue_key = "TEST-55"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, passw)


payload = {
"fields": {
"customfield_15035": [{"prop1":"xxxxx","prop2":"yyyyy","prop3":"zzzzz"}]
}
}


json_payload = json.dumps(payload)

headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}


response = requests.put(url.format(issue_key=issue_key), data=json_payload, headers=headers, auth=auth)

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).